# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded[react router v4]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react router v4 in my application. I am developing a dashboard which has a layout of top navigation, side navigation and main body. Side navigation has a list of links which when clicked routes to their component and render their component in another component which is called main body. I have broken down my dashboard component to top, side and main. In the index i have created a list of routes and is send those routes as a props to main body so that their i can render the routed component.

This way i get an error of

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Why is that so? How can i prevent from such issue? I will more than 10 links on the side bar.

Here is what i have done

index.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    main: () => <Dashboard />
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    main: () => <h2>dashboard</h2>
  },
  {
    path: '/email_template',
    main: () => <AdminEditor />
  }
];

class Dashboard extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav
          className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"
          role="navigation"
          style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
          <TopNavigation user={this.props.user} />
          <SideNavigation />
        </nav>
        <BodyWrapper routes={routes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


SideNavigation.js

<ul className="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li>
    <Link to="/">
      <i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw" /> Dashboard
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/email_template">
      <i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw" /> Email Template
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>

BodyWrapper.js

<div className="col-lg-12">
  <h1 className="page-header">
    {routes.map((route, index) => (
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        component={route.main}
      />
    ))}
  </h1>
</div>
```

Can anyone guide me the efficient way to handle such routes?

UPDATE

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Entity user={this.props.auth.user} />;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Links />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
            <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
            <Route
              strict
              path="/about"
              render={() => <div>About us Page</div>}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const userTypes = [
  { id: '4', val: Dashboard }, // Previous Above code is for this entity
  { id: '3', val: Dashboard3 },
  { id: '2', val: Dashboard2 },
  { id: '1', val: Dashboard1 }
];

const entity = props => {
  const redirectRoute = userTypes.filter(x => x.id === props.user.id);
  if (redirectRoute && redirectRoute.length) {
    const ComponentToRender = redirectRoute[0].val;
    return <ComponentToRender {...props} />;
  } else {
    return <div>can't get route. unknown issue.</div>;
  }
};
```

Comment: There is two time i have used Route because there will be 4 different dashboard as per the role of user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly all your routes should come under a router component, such as,

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
</Router>
```

secondly it doesn't make sense to pass in routes object to some other component, when all you can put all your presentational components right inside the router component, in your case just try out this code:

```
class Dashboard extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
     <Router>
      <div>
        <nav
          className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"
          role="navigation"
          style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
          <TopNavigation user={this.props.user} />
          <SideNavigation />
        </nav>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={<h2>dashboard</h2>}/>
        <Route path="/email_template" component={<AdminEditor />}/>
      </div>
     </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

For more information on react-router 4 tutorial and working check out this link: [reacttraining](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)